# Groovy Regex: Capture group in Switch Statement

Tags: regex, groovy

Given the following Groovy code switch statement:

```
def vehicleSelection = "Car Selected: Toyota"

switch (vehicleSelection) {
   case ~/Car Selected: (.*)/:

      println "The car model selected is "  + ??[0][1] 
}
```

Is it possible to extract the word "Toyota" *without* defining a new (`def`) variable?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is possible using the `lastMatcher` method added to `Matcher` by Groovy:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher

def vehicleSelection = 'Car Selected: Toyota'

switch( vehicleSelection ) {
   case ~/Car Selected: (.*)/: 
     println "The car model selected is ${Matcher.lastMatcher[0][1]}"
}
```

Comment: I would still have to declare `m` though. I was wondering if there was something like Perl's `$_`. If this is a limitation of Groovy maybe using a `def` is ok then.

Comment: Another way is to use `Matcher.lastMatcher.group(1)`

Comment: The import seems to be redundant.

Answer (score 8):

Building on tim_yates answer that was really helpful for me:

If you want avoid a bunch of "Matcher.lastMatcher" in your code you can create a helper function to act as an alias.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher

static Matcher getm()
{
    Matcher.lastMatcher
}

def vehicleSelection = 'Car Selected: Toyota'

switch( vehicleSelection ) {
    case ~/Car Selected: (.*)/: 
        println "The car model selected is ${m[0][1]}"
     break;
}
```